# C# SQL - Few questions about updating rows

Tags: c#, sql

I have a Website with 3 signup pages.
every page contains information, and all 3 pages are part of the signup process.
I know that `INSERT` command is used to create new rows. But in the `UPDATE` command, I must mention `WHERE` clause.
So, my question is, how can I `UPDATE` the same row I updated in the past pages.
I am using Visual Studio Community 2015.
Any help will be appreciated.

**First page code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class Sign_Up_SignUpMain_1_ : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;";
        str += "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;";
        str += "Integrated Security= True";
        string email, userName;
        //Page
        if (Page.IsValid == true)
        {
            email = txtEmail.Text;
            userName = txtUserName.Text;
            SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(str);
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Table] (Email, UserName) VALUES (@email, @userName);", c);
            sqlCommand.Connection = c;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", userName);
            c.Open();
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            c.Close();
            Response.Redirect("SignUp(2).aspx", true);
        }
        //Email
        if (rfvEmail.IsValid == false || revEmail.IsValid == false)
        { txtEmail.CssClass = "txtError"; }
        else
        { txtEmail.CssClass = "Text"; }
        //User Name
        if (rfvUserName.IsValid == false || revUserName.IsValid == false)
        { txtUserName.CssClass = "txtError"; }
        else
        { txtUserName.CssClass = "Text"; }
    }
}
```

**Second page code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class Sign_Up_SignUp_2_ : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;";
        str += "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;";
        str += "Integrated Security= True";
        string password;
        //Page
        if (Page.IsValid == true)
        {
            password = txtPass.Text;
            SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(str);
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Table] (Email, UserName) VALUES (@email, @userName);", c);
            Response.Redirect("SignUp(3).aspx", true);
        }
        //Password
        if (revPass.IsValid == false || rfvPass.IsValid == false)
        { txtPass.CssClass = "txtError"; }
        else
        { txtPass.CssClass = "Text"; }
        //Confirm Password
        if (rfvConPass.IsValid == false)
        { txtConPass.CssClass = "txtError"; }
        else
        { txtConPass.CssClass = "Text"; }
        //Compare Passwords
        if (cvPasswords.IsValid == false)
        {
            txtPass.CssClass = "txtError";
            txtConPass.CssClass = "txtError";
            txtPass.Text = "";
            txtConPass.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            txtPass.CssClass = "Text";
            txtConPass.CssClass = "Text";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to post code showing what you have so far and what you have tried.

Comment: Use id of first insert.

Comment: @Dmitry K. I have posted the code up, so far I tried to find in the internet how to import the primary key but I didn`t understand it.
@huseyin tugrul buyukisik how can I do these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I see your issue, you aren't passing the values that have already been inserted between pages. You can use the [Session State to pass objects between parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx)

On your current page, before redirecting to the next page, set all the information you want to retain in the session state:

```
Session["email"] = theirEmailAddress;
Session["username"] = theirUserName;
```

After storing the information you need in the session redirect to the next page and store the information on this page into the session as well.

Then finally on the last page you can access all of the session data and do a single SQL insert command. To access the session items you just do this:

```
string email = (string)(Session["email"]);
```

Comment: I didn't understand what the season statement does and how should I use it. Can you please explain?

Comment: It lets you store data that the user has input so you can access it at a later time. You need to store all of their information from their new user creation and then once they have input everything then you can use it all at once to do your SQL INSERT query. Im not sure how much clearer this can be. Look at the link I provided.